# Trying to parse a jsonarray within a jsonarray

Tags: android, json

I am parsing some json in an app and I have come across arrays that sometimes have information in it:

```
{
    "output": [
        {
            "id": "1521",
            "name": "Apples",
        }
    ]
}
```

and sometimes has nothing. e.g

```
{
    "output": [
        []
    ]
}
```

I was parsing it by

```
JSONArray output = c.getJSONArray("output");
int outputLength = output.length();

for (int q = 0; q < outputLength; q++) 
{
    JSONObject d = outputs.getJSONObject(q);
    id[q] = d.getInt("id");
    name[q] = d.getString("name");
}
```

but when it gets to the empty array it crashes.
I get the following error then:

```
01-19 01:08:00.237: W/System.err(17627): org.json.JSONException: Value [] at 0 of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

it crashes because it's trying to convert the jsonarray into an object and you can't do that so I tried getting the first array in output with:

```
JSONArray add = output.getJSONArray(0);
```

but that will crash as well because in the first output it's an object in it and not an array.
I don't have access or control over the json feed and I'm stuck at the moment as to how to parse the result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The *real* answer is: "Fix whatever is generating that horrible JSON".

If that's not an option you're going to have to figure out exactly what you have before trying to access it. The [JSONArray.optJSONObject()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html#optJSONObject%28int%29) method can help with this; it returns `null` if the specified index doesn't contain a `JSONObject`:

```
JSONArray output = c.getJSONArray("output");
for (int q = 0; q < outputLength; q++) 
{
    JSONObject d = output.optJSONObject(q);
    if (d != null)
    {
        id[q] = d.getInt("id");
        name[q] = d.getString("name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Because you're parsing everything in the enclosing `JSONArray` as a`JSONObject`, all the entries would have to be formatted that way. For that to work, your source string would have to look like this:

```
[
{
    "output": [
        {
            "id": "1521",
            "name": "Apples"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "output": [
        []
    ]
}
]
```

Everything in the top-level`JSONArray` is now a `JSONObject` and can be parsed accordingly. What's inside of those objects is your business (empty arrays are OK). A good resource for checking if a given JSON string is valid is [this](http://www.jsonlint.org) website.